# Calculate time difference between first and last row in Excel column or .hdf file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time

I have the "Datetime" column in Excel and also in a .hdf Dataframe. How can I calculate the time difference (in hours, min or sec) between the first and the last row? here is how my data look like; please remember that my data has few thousands rows. Therefore I cannot write a code and manually add these dates:
(P.S. I am very new to python, this is my very first code)

please see the table below to see how it looks like:
as you can see, my date and time are in one column:

```
     Datetime         Header:           Machine_started
2021-02-02 14:33:09   Data              1
2021-02-02 14:33:09   Data              1
2021-02-02 14:33:11   Data              1
2021-02-02 14:41:36   Data              1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"Datetime": ['2021-02-02 14:33:09', '2021-02-02 14:33:09', '2021-02-02 14:33:11', '2021-02-02 14:41:36'],
         "Header": ['Data', 'Data','Data','Data'], 
        "1_2_eBeam_started": [1,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# creating dataframe

df['Datetime'].dtype
# dtype is object 
# convert it to datetime

df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

df['Datetime'].iloc[0]   # this is first row

df['Datetime'].iloc[-1]   # this is last row

# difference in seconds:

(df['Datetime'].iloc[-1] - df['Datetime'].iloc[0])/np.timedelta64(1,'s')

#output 507.0

# You can also get the difference in minutes, hours, etc. by rplacing 's' by 'm' or 'h' in np.timedelta64(1,'s')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked just fine as I needed. I cannot vote yet since my account is new but thank you anyway!

Comment: Please accept my answer by clicking 'tick ' mark near vote button.

Comment: Dear Talha, I try that and it gives me a message: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

It is because my account is still fresh and I need to have more activities to collect some points.

Comment: Thank you dear @Python_bug.. it is just below the vote button you tried to click. green color arrow. nevermind.. have a great day!

Comment: I got what you mean. It is accepted. Thanks!